# Question About A Problem About Rational Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, fractions, rational-numbers

[image]
I'm a bit confused about what I am supposed to prove in this step of the problem. Am I supposed to prove that for any positive integer $T$, no matter it's size, I can always find positive integers $b<c<d<etc.....$ that are greater than $T$, and such that $a = 1/b + 1/c + 1/d...etc $?

**Also, could you avoid giving me any hints on how to solve this problem, or information about rational numbers, when answering the question?** I still want to try and figure out how to solve this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do not post pictures of text but use Latex

Comment: @DietrichBurde So are you saying that T isn't any arbitary positive but T is 2? I'm asking this because the question is written as though T was a specific positive integer, but I find it very strange if that's the case. After all, because 0<a<1, can't you just set T=1? There's no way the problem is that trivial.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Because that should be already proved in part A)! Here's the link to the problem:https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/resources/potm/2019-20/POTM-20-5-FEB-P.pdf.  And also, to be blunt, I think you are misunderstanding my question. I'm asking what does T mean in the  question, but I don't see how your comments connect to that so far.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I highly doubt I'm supposed to prove it for T=1. The question has defined a, as being less than 1. If any one of b,c, etc was equal to 1, you wouldn't be able to express a number less than 1 using that. That's why I'm confused. I'm wondering if T is an arbitary integer, or if it's a specific integer I'm supposed to look for.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I suppose I could express 2/7 as = 1/6 + 1/12 +1/28. I'm sorry about being so slow though, but I still don't understand what T is supposed to mean. Are you saying T = 5? Or is T any arbitrary integer; and we can express any rational number, with numbers greater than T, where T is any arbitrary integer?

Comment: The denominators should be bigger than $T$.

Comment: Historical corner : [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction)...

Comment: The duplicate mentioned here refers to another problem where $T=2$. This one appears more difficult. Voting to reopen. +1 to asker.

Comment: Your understanding of the problem is correct. And therefore you are supposed to prove that for any positive integer $T$, no matter its size...

Comment: @ParamanandSingh If you are able to write $\alpha$ as $\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+...+\frac{1}{n_k}$ then replace $\frac{1}{n}$ with $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ repeatedly until all the denominators are bigger than $T$. Am I correct?

Comment: @YuiToCheng: It should work fine although your trick was not obvious to me. Also I think there should be a direct approach which tries to find the denominators based on $\alpha$ and $T$. Therefore I voted to reopen.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see. You may want to post your request [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today).